# .Net Core 3.0 Angular application post request parameter is always NULL

Tags: c#, typescript, post, .net-core, angular8

I would like to note that this is my first .Net Core Angular project and i apologize if the question may seem obvious, i looked at similar questions but my problem still persists so i guess i am doing something wrong.

So i have created a .Net Core 3.0 Angular project in Visual Studio and created a select menu that on change sends a POST request with the selected value, however on the controller the received POST is always NULL

This is my HTML

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="languageChanged($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let language of languages | keyvalue:returnZero" value="{{language.key}}">{{language.value}}</option>
</select>
```

For the POST request on the client side i have tried the two following approaches :

```
    this.http.post("Language", lang).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
}, error => console.error(error));
```

and

```
this.http.post<LanguageInterface>("Language", lan).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
}, error => console.error(error));
```

where

```
export interface LanguageInterface { language: string; }
```

On the server side

```
public class Language
{
  public string language { get; set; } 
}
```

on the HTTP post i have also tried two things

```
public IActionResult Post(Language lan)
{
  // logic
  return Ok();
}
```

and i have tried to change the method to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm]Language lan)
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different questions in your post that I'd be happy to tackle for you:

### Why doesn't Language get populated in your controller method?

You indicate that the method on your API controller looks like:

```cs
public IActionResult Post(Language lan)
{
  // logic
  return Ok();
}
```

You don't indicate if you're configuring Endpoints in your setup, so I'll assume not. You should update this with to instead look like the following. This will do two things: 1) The first line will inform ASP.NET Core that this method should match a POST request with the named template and 2) the `[FromBody]` attribute in the argument tells ASP.NET Core where to populate the value from (your POST body).

```
[HttpPost("Language")] //Handles a call to /language as you attempt in both your first and second calls from Angular.
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Language lan)
{
  //logic
  return Ok();
}
```

### Should you use `async` and `Task<T>` in your last controller sample

Unless you're performing asynchronous activities in your `//logic` comment, there's no reason to decorate the method with `async` or have it return a `Task<IActionResult>`. The example above is more than sufficient.

### Are you even populating any data to send?

This would be worth a peek at your network request to verify, but unless you're doing some mapping in your Angular component, you're setting the value of the option field to "language.key", but in your call to `this.http.post`, you pass in `lang` and subsequently `lan` which both are not otherwise used in your example code. As such, I can't dig much into what might be going on there, but it could be worth opening your network tools in your browser and confirm that the POST request to your server is actually populating with the intended data from the Angular component.

### You might be misunderstanding the TypeScript syntax on the Angular side in your calls to `this.http.post`

You indicate that you're trying to send data with:

```js
this.http.post<LanguageInterface>("Language", lan).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
}, error => console.error(error));
```

My concern here is merely derived from this second example you give given that you're passing in data from a `LanguageInterface`, presumably into the `lan` parameter somehow, but you also reference that at `this.http.post<LanguageInterface>`. The use of <> on the method is to type the response that you're expecting from the call and is not properly used here. Rather, because your controller methods in ASP.NET Core both simply return an `Ok()` `ActionResult`, there's no anticipated type for the response, so this wouldn't make much sense here.

In this case, your first post call from Angular uses the correct syntax:

```js
this.http.post("Language", lang).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
}, error => console.error(error));
```

The result will merely contain the `HttpResponse` and there's not expected to be a body in the response back to you, much less one that should be typed to anything.

### Conclusion

Again, I can't speak to how you're mapping between the form and your call to POST the data, but feel free to provide more of your sample code and notify me in a comment and I'd be happy to review it as well.

#### Within your Angular component

```js
this.http.post("Language", lang).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
}, error => console.error(error));
```

#### Your ASP.NET Core controller method

```cs
[HttpPost("Language")] //Handles a call to /language as you attempt in both your first and second calls from Angular.
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Language lan)
{
  //logic
  return Ok();
}
```

### Why does `[HttpPost("Language")]` break this?

You didn't originally provide the controller signature in your question, so this wasn't obvious before. Because your `[Route]` attribute on the controller is set as `[Route("[controller]")]`, it is using an ASP.NET Core convention to use the name of the controller before "Controller" - in your case, your class is "LanguageController", so any request to /Language will wind up pointing here as a valid option.

Since I then suggested a route on `[HttpPost("Language")]`, that further adds to the pattern required to match. If you sent a POST request to `localhost:<port>/Language/Language`, you'd see it match on the method as expected.

To remedy this then, merely changing the attribute on the method to `[HttpPost]` and eliminating the template argument will mean that this will match a call to `localhost:<port>/Language`, assuming this is the only POST method with this signature in the controller.

Comment: Hello Xaniff, thank you for your reply!

From enum i am getting the index for the menu languages

export enum Languages {
  English = "English",
  Bulgarian = "Български",
}

I have tried your suggestion but now i am getting another error
POST http://localhost:51871/Language 404 (Not Found)

controller code:

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class LanguageController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("Language")]
        public IActionResult Post(Language lan)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

    }

Best regards!

Comment: @spstrademark Ah, that would be because you're providing the [Route] attribute on your controller. If you were to send the POST request to /Language/Language, you'd see it hit. As it is, change the attribute on your method (assuming it's the only POST method on your controller) to `[HttpPost]` and you can send the POST request directly to /Language (routing via the template on your controller and not specifying any further template on the method itself).

Comment: @sptrademark I've updated my answer to address the question posed in your answer of why my suggestion didn't work. Check out the bottom of my post.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for the detailed explanation! I can confirm all is working as expected. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

So with the helpful answer from Xaniff and some reading i managed to get it to work!
I have made the following changes

Within the angular component:

```
let post: LanguageInterface = {
  language: this.currentLanguage,
}
this.http.post("Language", post).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
  this.data.changeLanguage(this.currentLanguage);
  this.toastr.success("Ok");
 }, error => console.error(error));
```

I am using the interface i have created to set the recieved value and posting it to the controller
The controller code:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class LanguageController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Language lan)
    {
        // logic
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

Even thought this is working i would appreciate a reply why  " [HttpPost("Language")] " makes it broken.

Sincerely, Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem here but no one supplied the answer I came upon myself so I am writing this in hopes that it helps the next bum like me.

It turns out, in .net core model binding(any version) for POST, regardless of if its angular, jquery, or what have you, the variable NAME of the post method matters.

you have this:

```
public IActionResult Post(Language lan)
{
  // logic
  return Ok();
}
```

but what you need is this

```
public IActionResult Post(Language language)
{
  // logic
  return Ok();
}
```

emphasis on the fact that the variable name is the same as the class name with the first letter being lower.

this took me far too long to solve for what it is, and I hope it helps you or some other person dealing with the same circumstance.